# Estimate using Big-0 notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

**Estimate (using O() notation) the number of additions and multiplications
performed by the code below (as a function of n):**

**`idx = 1
temp = 0
while ( idx < n )
temp = temp + idx
idx = 2(idx)`**

However, there is no answer to the problem and it is never mentioned again. I am wondering how i would go about this problem and how to come to a solution as it could still appear on the final exam for my course.

Comment: So, solve the inequality, that is the number of times you enter. Notice that idx at every point is of the form $idx=2^k$ for $k=0,k=1,\cdots$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to count the number of times in the loop.

If the condition was removed then $\text{idx}_k = 2^k$.

The condition is satisfied as long as $2^k <n $ or $k = \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$, so
since we have $k=0,...,\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$, the 
loop is entered $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor+1$ times.

Each time through there is one addition and one multiplication so the exact number
is given by same formula.

In terms of $O$ notation, I would write $O(\log_2 n)$.